# Как получить результат confirm() js?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможность в одной функции перехватить результат confirm() из другой функции?

```
function one() {
  if(confirm()) ...
}

function two() {
  let res = confirmResultInOneFunction
}
```

Comment: Есть возможность.

Answer (score 2):

```
function odnaFunkcija(resultConfirm) {
  console.log(resultConfirm);
}

function drugajaFunkcija() {
  return confirm("Confirm?");
}

let res = drugajaFunkcija();
odnaFunkcija(res);
```

Comment: `return confirm("Confirm?");` == `▲`

Comment: Я не совсем корректно объяснил задачу. В одной функции есть проверка if(confirm()) { //..... }
Во второй функции нужно перехватить результат ответа и выполнить определенные действия согласно результата.

Comment: @Виталий "перехватить результат ответа" - ??

Comment: @Igor верно, перехватить результат ответа confirm()

Comment: @Виталий В программировании нет термина "перeхватить". Что Вы под этим понимаете? Какая функция в какой момент выполняется? Как эти две функции между собой связаны? Сохраните результат `confirm()` в переменную и используйте эту переменную в функции `two`.

Comment: @Виталий Если Вы будете вести себя как партизан, я поставлю Вам минус.

Answer (score 0):

```
function one() {
  if(res = confirm()) ...
    return res;
}

function two() {
  let res = one()
}
```

Перехватываются события. А результаты передаются по значению и по ссылке.
Совет - читайте mdn и другую полезную для начинающих литературу.